# Gatsby works fine during development but throws error during build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am passing data from one page to another in gatsby. First page code:

```
let state = {book: book, src: src}
return (
<div className="book__holder">
    <Link to="/pdf/" state={state}>
    <Card
        hoverable
        style={{ width: 240 }}
        cover={<img alt={book} 
                    src={url}
                    />}
        >
        <Meta
            title={book}
            description={faculty+" "+year+"-"+part}
        />
    </Card> 
    </Link> 
</div>
```

This data is used in **pdf** page as:

```
const PDFPage = props =>{
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
       <SEO title={props.location.state.book} />
       <NavBar></NavBar>
       <Embed src={props.location.state.src} type="application/pdf">
       </Embed>

     </React.Fragment>
    )}

export default PDFPage
```

Everything is fine when using **gatsby develop** but when i use **gatsby build** it throws following error:

```
error Building static HTML for pages failed

See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help https://gatsby.app    
/debug-html

  11 |   return (
  12 |   <React.Fragment>
> 13 |     <SEO title={props.location.state.book} keywords={[`gatsby`,  
           `application`, `react`]} />
     |                                      ^
  14 |     <NavBar></NavBar>
  15 |     <Embed src={props.location.state.src} type="application/pdf">    
           </Embed>
  16 | 


       WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'book' of undefined

        - pdf.js:13 PDFPage
         lib/src/pages/pdf.js:13:38
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Your `state` is undefined. Please kindly check if you are passing the state down correctly in the routes.

Comment: As i said above when i am using gastby develop everything is working. PDF loads properly, state is set. But when i run gatsby build error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sometimes you’ll want to pass data from the source page to the linked page. You can do this by passing a state prop to the Link component... The linked page will have a `location` prop containing a nested `state` object structure containing the passed data.

[Passing Props to Link targets](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#passing-props-to-link-targets)

While the following demo is not actually using gatsby, it is using reach router (and gatsby uses reach router under the hood).

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Router, Link } from "@reach/router";

const App = () => {
  let state = {
    name: 'Ron',
    book: {
      title: 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows', 
      author: 'J. K. Rowling', 
      progress: '80%'
    }
  }

  return (
  <div>
    <h1>App</h1>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/" state={state}>Home</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="dashboard" state={state} >Dashboard</Link>
    </nav>

    <Router>
      <Home path="/" />
      <Dashboard path="/dashboard" />
    </Router>
  </div>
)};

const Home = ({location}) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Welcome { location.state.name }</h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
);

const Dashboard = ({location}) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <p>Hi { location.state.name }.</p>
    <p>You have read { location.state.book.progress } of { location.state.book.title } by { location.state.book.author }.</p>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ze6ktr)

Answer (score 4):

Gatsby will throw error during production build, since location is not available during server-side rendering.

One way to make sure the build doesn't throw an error is to:

1. Check for the window in componentDidMount
2. Map the location prop to state
3. Render the value from your state instead of directly from props

In componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return;
  }
  this.setState(() => ({ playerName: this.props.location.state.playerName }));
}
```

In render()

```
render() {
  return <div>{this.state.playerName}</div>;
}
```

credit to this thread, [How to get previous url in react gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942047/how-to-get-previous-url-in-react-gatsby)